# In Yii controller

Tags: php, controller, yii

I'm newbie and learning Yii framework where Im designing first small application and got stuck on this position where I need your attention as your guys are guru.

I have a 'City name' list on main layout in header section where a user select a 'City' then I would like to pass that City_id to 'PostController' and search for that city post and display the last Postonly.

Any idea how to handle this.

I look forward to hear from you guys soon and will appreciated an early reply.

Khan

Comment: Do you have some more information you could add to your question? What are your ActiveRecord Models? Do you have a City model, or is City a database column of your Post model? Are the city names links or is there a dropdown menu or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I got some how manage it.

Comment: It would be nice to post your answer here.

Comment: @Lourdas Argee with you!

Comment: @Khan It would be really NICE of you to share your 'some how' with us after asked...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard  to pass the selected city value to your PostCtonroller, you can then have your PostController call a function within one of your models to run whatever search you need on your database layer. You then take those results, pass them back to the controller and render a new page with your result. You can also do everything with Ajax so its nice and dynamic, but if you're new it would be best to use the basics first.

Also check out the yii framework website as they have a screencast (Video) about using their built in CRUD features.